# How to convert date to timestamp

Tags: shell, date

I saw this `date` command:

```
date -d @1332468005 '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Resulting in :

```
2012-03-22 22:00:05
```

How can I convert it back from `2012-03-22 22:00:05` to `1332468005` with bash shell?

Answer (score 26):

`man date` will give you the details of how to use the date command.

To convert long date in standard format into Unix epoc time (%s):
`date -d '2012-03-22 22:00:05 EDT' +%s`

Comment: It just didn't work for date like 'Пн 17 окт 2022 15:49:09 EEST'

Answer (score 9):

MacOS - `date -j -f "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S" '2012:03:22 22:00:05' +%s`

Answer (score 2):

On **BSD OS** (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD), `date` doesn't support `-d` flag. Use instead `-j` flag ("Parse the provided date and time and display the result without changing the clock") and `strftime` string format.

```
$ TZ=UTC date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2012-03-22 22:00:05" +%s
1332453605
```

Comment: This may have been better suited as an update to the already existing (and virtually identical) answer that deals with macOS?